# Halo CE Windows 10 dx fatal error

Tags: windows-10, gaming, directx, directx-9

[image: Error message]

This is the error I get when I try to open Halo CE. So far I've tried installing directx web installer but I already have the latest dx so it was useless. Not sure what else to do. Can I get some help solving this?

Comment: I have tried installing DX 9c but the setup for it tells I "must be running windows 98, windows millennium edition, windows 200, windows xp, or windows server family to install dx 9" https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34429 this is the download that I used

Comment: I ran that one as well and it didn't work because I have a newer version of DX

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to play on Windows 10 with a patch that Bungie provided several years ago.

[Halo PC/CE 1.0.10 now available](http://bungie.net/en/Forum/Post/64943622/0/0/0/0)